# C++ template function with pointer argument taken from iterator gives error

Tags: c++, pointers, boost-iterators, template-function

I am sorry if the title was not descriptive enough, I have no idea what is wrong with this:

```
  template <class S, class P> 
  P* findPolicy(boost::ptr_vector<P> &policies,S *state)
  {
    typename boost::ptr_vector<P>::iterator it;
    for ( it = policies.begin(); it != policies.end(); ++it)
    {
      if ( *it->getState() == state)
      {
        return &(*it);
      }
    }
  }
```

When I call the above function from within the following member function:

```
template <class S> template <class P>
void Policy<S>::updateOptimal(boost::ptr_vector<P> &policies)
{
  S *curr_state = state;
  boost::ptr_vector<Action> actions = curr_state->getAllActions();
  P *best_pol;
  boost::ptr_vector<Action>::iterator iter;
  for (iter = actions.begin(); iter != actions.end(); ++iter)
  {
    if (iter->getNextState())
    {
      S *s = dynamic_cast<S *>(iter->getNextState());
      P *temp_pol = var::findPolicy<S,P>(policies,s);
      if (temp_pol->getValue() > best_pol->getValue())
      {
        opt_Action = &(*iter);
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

I always get:
`policy.hpp:237: error: no matching function for call to 'findPolicy(boost::ptr_vector<Greedy<guState>, boost::heap_clone_allocator, std::allocator<void*> >&, State*&)`

Comment: You should try to work on the question, it is quite confusing. It took me a while to realize that half of the error message was gone, and even with the whole error message there is no clear indication as to which of the options for the code produced that output. My advice would be showing the template definition, and showing the function that is making the call as it is (remove unrelated code, but leave all type definitions for the arguments to the template). It might be the case that the compiler lists a set of candidates in the error message. If that is the case, add them to the question.

Comment: I have edited the entire question showing the two functions. Please let me know if it is more clear now what I am trying to do.

Comment: First try the obvious things: Are they in the same translation unit? Have you included the file where `findPolicy` is defined? What is `var`? Is it a namespace? enclosing type? Have you tried reducing the code to a smaller example that can be compiled separatedly? The question is much better anyway :)

Comment: This seems to have undergone edits. What's the state of the question now? Is there still a problem?

Comment: The question remains the same, why do I get this error when calling var::findPolicy(). var is a namespace. It works for many other functions grouped under it. The exact code I use in function findPolicy (the iteration and if statement) if copy-pasted in the second function updateOptimal(), it works fine. I believe it is a problem with either passing the iterator as an argument or deducing template parameters.

Comment: @Alex: You squash the parmeter deduction by explicitely specifying `findPolicy<S, P>`. What happens if you allow the arguments to be deduced? Also, is there a list of possible alternative function calls? Generally, there will be, and that's a good first clue as to why your function isn't being called.

Comment: @Dennis I'm not sure I understand what you mean by allowing the arguments to be deduced. How would I do that ? I have no alternative function calls for this specific function. I have tried various different ways for the syntax, even implicitly specifing the type to use.

Comment: When you call `findPolicy<S, P>(...)` you explicitly state which template parameters you want the compiler to use for that call.  If you do `findPolicy(...)`, the template parameters will be deduced from the arguments you pass the function.  And generally, that particular error is followed by a list of functions with the same name that didn't get selected... specifically, it should list the function you expect to get called.  By comparing that function signature, with the function signature in that initial error message, why the function isn't being selected can generally be deduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't deduce the template argument for `S` and `P` however since you explicitly call the method with arguments you're skipping deduction and so the compiler is simply telling you it can't find that specific match.

The most likely reason it can't find it is because either S or P are templates and not actual types. If so then you need to specify that by adding a `typename` in front of them.  Try this instead:

```
P *temp_pol = var::findPolicy<typename S, typename P>(policies, s);
```

Also note the the following was probably a typo:

```
template <class S> template <class P>
void Policy<S>::updateOptimal(boost::ptr_vector<P> &policies)
```

should probably be:

```
template <class S, class P>
void Policy<S>::updateOptimal(boost::ptr_vector<P> &policies)
```

**Edit:** Also noticed a strange use of a previous parameter you are specifying `P` in your function but passing a `boost::ptr_vector<P>&` into it and apparently your template arguments and function parameters are not in the same order as you have `<S, P>` then pass them in as `(policies, s)`. Try to avoid confusing or misleading code like this.

I'm assuming you didn't write this as you don't have a specific question so this may also fall under don't use something you don't understand as well. There are probably other issues as yet undiscovered and you may be better off going back to the drawing board and coming up with a design that works that is maintainable for you.

Comment: That doesn't work. Deniis Zickefoose answered it, it was a deduction error. Thank you though.

Comment: Ah, well that's good! Let the compiler deduce function template arguments. It's less typing for you and helps uncover issues by causing errors that are more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what's wrong with your code examples:

somewhere (not described in the question), you have the actual declaration of the function, and it has an error. It looks like this:

```
template<class S, class P>
P* findPolicy(boost::ptr_vector<P> &policies,S *state);
```

But there is some error in this kind of line. One of the parameters is wrong. So you get the error. The code you posted is ok.